# Can't refresh the page after form submission

Tags: django, django-forms

I am building a comment system in a blog like Django project. There is a form at the end of each article (that works fine). I want to make it so that when the form is submitted, the page refreshes and the comment is visible.

(Before I just linked to the front page of the blog, and the comments were saved and displayed)

I try the code below, but the page is stuck in "loading", then displays a {{ ip_adress }} can't be reached, but nevertheless writes the DB. This is my views.py

```
def view_article(request, id):
    try:
        article =get_object_or_404(Article, id=id)
        comments = CommentArticle.objects.filter(article_id=id)
        form = CommentForm(request.POST or None, initial={'article_id': id})
        url = "submit_comment/" + str(id)
        if form.is_valid():
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            poster_name = form.cleaned_data['poster_name']
            article_id = id
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('refresh_article'))  

    except Article.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404

    return render( request, 'blog/view_article.html', locals())

def refresh_article(request, id):
    url = 'view_article' + str(id)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(url))
```

Does anyone has any clue? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You're entering an infinite loop. You need to only validate the form on the post.

```
def view_article(request, id):
    try:
        article =get_object_or_404(Article, id=id)
        comments = CommentArticle.objects.filter(article_id=id)
        form = CommentForm(request.POST or None, initial={'article_id': id})
        url = "submit_comment/" + str(id)
        if request.method == "POST" and form.is_valid():
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            poster_name = form.cleaned_data['poster_name']
            article_id = id
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('view_article', kwargs={'id': id}))  

    except Article.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404

    return render( request, 'blog/view_article.html', locals())
```

Also, you don't need to redirect to another view, to redirect back to the current view. You can simply just redirect back to the same view.

Comment: Then the action parameter of the form in my template should be :
<form action="{% url 'view_article' %}/{{ id }}" method="post">
but it doesn't seem to find the reverse.

Comment: You have a bug in your urls.py definition. You need to include the argument in the url. You'll find examples in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/